# How to list all url of contents?

Tags: views

I have so many content type like `article`, `contribution`, `event`, `c_program` etc.

For all content url alias is,

`[site_name]/[content type name]/title`

But we have some url alias that are like this,

`[site name]/title`

So, I want to list all url of,

`[site name]/title` format

How I can I list them out?

Comment: Just wondering, why do you want to list them out?

Comment: I guess the OP needs to correct the latter type of path aliases.

Comment: You could query the url_alias table.

Answer (score 1):

Use Drupal [Pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto)

After enabling it go to `admin/config/search/path/patterns` and under **Default path pattern (applies to all content types with blank patterns below)** fieldset you'll get what you want.

Add your desired format there:

```
[site:name]/[node:title]
```

[image]

Once the configuration is done, click on `admin/config/search/path/update_bulk` and select **Content paths** from the given options.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Views Excel Export](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_export_xls). And export all URL's and filter them in Microsoft excel

> Simple module that allows to export Views data to Excel (xls).
>
> Uses php-excel class with UTF8 support.

Comment: In that case, the OP should first create a view showing all the path aliases, should not he?